# How to convert buildbot Property to string value

Tags: python, properties, buildbot

**Problem:**

I am trying to figure out how to convert a buildbot Property into a string value. I really don't have much experience with buildbot other than what I have read in the docs and someone elses code.
The issue is I have a Property that contains a path. I need to get the path as a string so that I can use some python functions such as 'split' and 'basename' to retrieve specific elements of the path.

**What I Have Tried:**

There is a property mapped like so

`"artifact.output":"S3://dev/artifacts/out/package1.tar.gz"`

When I call `path.os.basename(util.Property("artifact.output"))` it complains that Property has no 'rfind' method. I also tried using `util.Interpolate` but again, it has the same issue.  Finally, I tried `str(util.Property("artifact.output"))` but it just outputs `Property("artifact.output")`.

**Question:**

Is it possible to retrieve a buildbot Property as a string value?

note: I was only able to find one other post from someone back on 2014 asking the same thing but no answer.

Answer (score 4):

A `Property` is not a string by itself, but it's a class that implements an `IRenderable` interface. This interface defines something, that can be "rendered" into a string when needed. To render a `Property` or any renderable (eg. the `util.Interpolate` object), you need a an `IProperties` provider.

The question is where to get such provider and how to render it. When implementing your own step, you can use the `Build` instance that you can access from `self.build` as such provider and use it to render the property.

```python
class ExampleBuildStep(BuildStep):
    def __init__(self, arg, **kwargs):
        """
        Args:
            arg - any string, Property or any renderable that will be rendered in run
        """
        self.arg = arg
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def run(self):
        # the renderedcommand will be the string representation of the self.arg
        renderedcommand = yield self.build.render(self.arg)
```

In the example above, the `ExampleBuildStep` takes an argument arg that will be rendered inside the `run()` function. Note that the arg does not have to be property, it can be a tring as well. You can now create use the build step with renderables:

```python
step = ExampleBuildStep(util.Property("artifact.output"))
step = ExampleBuildStep(util.Interpolate('%(prop:artifact.output)s'))
step = ExampleBuildStep("string argument")
```

Comment: Just a "renderables = [ 'arg' ]" at a class level should be fine without explicit call to build.render

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Interpolate` for that purpose:

```
util.Interpolate('string before ' + '%(prop:artifact.output)s' + ' string after')
```

Comment: this won't work as in the post from 2014 which author pointed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864100/interpolate-wont-work-when-passing-a-property-triggered-builder-which-will-us

Comment: I've seen a similar issue with Interpolate.  It works fine when passing Interpolate as input to ShellCommand or other buildbot function, but when I used as arg to my own class, it complains its not a string type.  Strange

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to the `BuildStep` object, you can grab properties already formatted as a string via the `getProperty()` method.

If you wanted to grab the "workername" as a string and print it, you could call:

```
workerName = step.getProperties().getProperty('workername','wname')
print("workerName: %s" % workerName)
```

Note: `workername` is one of the [Common Build Properties](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/configuration/properties.html#common-build-properties) you should always expect to find, alongside the user-defined ones.

`getProperty()` is defined in [properties.py](https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/blob/master/master/buildbot/process/properties.py):

```
def getProperty(self, name, default=None):
    return self.properties.get(name, (default,))[0]
```

Remember to switch branches from 'master' to whatever your version of buildbot is.